# Issue in reading Gzip file in C#

Tags: c#

With below method I am trying to read a .gz file but I am getting error as *"Stream does not support reading. (Parameter 'stream')"*. I have no clue about this error and would like to know what this mean here and if possible any suggestion on fixing it. File is of this format test1.csv.gz and The error is returned at line using(var unzipper....

```
public async Task<string> ReadStream(string containerName, string digestFileName,string fileName, string connectionString)
{
    string data = string.Empty;
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    MemoryStream contents = await DownloadBlob(containerName, digestFileName, connectionString);
    if (fileExtension == ".gz")
    {
        using (var unzipper = new GZipStream(contents, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(unzipper, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    else
    {
       data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contents.ToArray());
    }
    return data;
}
```

DownloadBlob:

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();            
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    if (blob.Exists())
        using (memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
        }
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: What does `DownloadBlob` do? My suspicion is that it returns a `MemoryStream` which has already been disposed, or perhaps a *subclass* of `MemoryStream` which has `CanRead` overridden to return false. (Your error is because of [this check](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs,60), where `contents.CanRead` returned `false`)

Comment: You are correct DownloadBlob returns memoryStream. how do i fix this. i cant change downloadblob .

Comment: Does it return a `MemoryStream` **which has been disposed**, or perhaps a subclass of `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the source of `DownloadBlob`?

Comment: done. added download blob

Comment: Right, yes that disposes the `MemoryStream` before returning it. Once the `MemoryStream` has been disposed, it can't be used any more. Remove your `using` statement

Comment: can you post the answer as what should be the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DownloadBlob` method returns a `MemoryStream`, but it puts that `MemoryStream` in a [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), which disposes the `MemoryStream`.

Once a `MemoryStream` has been disposed, you can't (really) continue to use in. In particular, `GzipStream` will throw an exception if you ask it to decompress from a stream which has been disposed.

You should remove that `using` statement: you shouldn't be disposing the `MemoryStream`. In fact, you end up creating two `MemoryStream` instances, which is pointless.

You'll also find that you need to rewind the `MemoryStream` before you can read it again, which you do by setting its `Position = 0`.

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();            

    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    if (blob.Exists())
    {
        await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream;
}
```

**However**, think carefully about what should happen if `blob.Exists()` returns false. At the moment you'll return a `MemoryStream` which doesn't contain anything, and so trying to decompress it will fail. You probably want to throw an exception in this case, and handle that exception further up the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

With your `using` statement, you dispose the stream.

Don't do that there, the caller should do that.

Comment: can you please show in code what do you mean by not disposing the stream

Comment: Remove `using (memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {}`, but keep the code within.